# how to get id or attribute value from a tag from javascript srtring

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the id or attribute value of a tag from javascript variable i.e 
all the html content are in a javascript variable.  So i am not able to get the id of a perticular tag from the javascript variable.

Here is my code sample.

```
var v="<html><head></head><body id='htmlBody' ></body></html>"
var chk = $(v);
alert($(chk).find("body").attr('id'));
```

Thanks,
Dipesh

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zM3v7/1/

Comment: Looks the html parser is ignoring the `html`, `head` and `body` tags, try using xml parser as given in the fiddle

Comment: Works in Chrome Linux (v30). Output is: `#document "htmlBody"`

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting one. It doesn't seem to recognise exactly any of those elements (html, head, body). I tried adding a title element into the head it recognises that and I tried adding a p element into the body and it recognises that too.

You might only be able to get this with a regular expression?

```
var v="<html><head></head><body id='htmlBody'></body></html>"
var matches = v.match(/body id='(.*?)'/i);
alert(matches[1]);
```